# Помогите сделать цикл на python

Tags: python

Помогите пожалуйста.Как сделать так ... Например из числа 1 берется hash (b вариант), из полученного хэша берется еще один хэш( х вариант) и т. д. 
Как изменить код ,чтобы можно было просто задать количество вариантов например 10( не прописывая x=,y= и т.д.)

```
import hashlib

for _ in xrange(10):

 b= hashlib.sha256("1").hexdigest()
 print (b)
 x=hashlib.sha256(b).hexdigest()
 print (x)
 y=hashlib.sha256(x).hexdigest()
 print(y)
```

Comment: У Вас `x` используется дважды (в цикле и внутри него) - так и задумано? Если я правильно понял, можно написать что-то вроде `b = "1"` а потом `for _ in range(10): b = hashlib.sha256(b).hexdigest()`

Comment: Исправил , так не задуманно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы хотите получить вот это? (десятикратное применение, на выходе один объект)

```
f = open('text.txt')
for line in f: 
    b = line
    for _ in range(10):
          b = hashlib.sha256(b).hexdigest()
          print (b)
```

или это: (десятикратное применение, на выходе все промежуточные состояния в списке)

```
b = ["1"]
for i in range(1,11):
      b.append(hashlib.sha256(b[i-1]).hexdigest())
      print(b[i])
```

Comment: Спасибо 1 вариант., не думал что это так просто) Решил , что при таком варианте он будет брать хэш из одного и того же числа)

Comment: Можно еще вопрос... Как сделать так что значение b бралось из файла ,txt . И если в файле (например) 3 строки , к каждому значению строки применялся этот код последовательно например 10 раз

Comment: пожалуйста помогите

Comment: Не работает .пишет IndentationError: expected an indented block   .... с указанием на b=f

Comment: Я отредактировал ответ, добавив туда чтение

Comment: другая ошибка TypeError: must be string or buffer, not file

Comment: к строчке b = hashlib.sha256(b).hexdigest(

Comment: Надо ........      b = line

Comment: в принципе я так же делал. проблема в том что правильное вычисление только первое , а последующие нет

Comment: в чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: точнее вообще результат полностью отличается от реального

Comment: От чего отличается?

Comment: Если например задать b  в ручную (b ="1") то все работает норм и результаты верны. Если же через файл text.txt  где будет одна строчка с 1. То результаты хэшей совсем другие и не правильные

Comment: Есть мысли ,что сделать?

Comment: С кодировками разбирайтесь

Comment: все файлы кодированы в одном формате.Есть мысли что предпринять?

Comment: Вы задали конкретный вопрос и получили на него конкретный ответ. Новые вопросы нужно задавать отдельно - так работает SO. Кодировки - имеются в виду Ansi. utf, Unicode, но тонкостей в обращении Python с ними я не знаю.

Comment: Я обратил внимание, что пометка о решении вопроса снята. Разве ответ перестал отвечать на поставленный вопрос о создании цикла?

Comment: Поставил... просто не могу задать вопрос .Пишет  что достигнут лимит вопросов ... а проблему не могу решить . с кодировкой все проверил (там все в норме).

Comment: Ниже я более подробно описал проблему

Comment: Если сможете помочь с решением буду очень благодарен

Comment: У меня Python 3, у Вас, судя по xrange - 2. В этом деле они ведут себя совсем по-разному. И у меня даже не принимается строка как параметр.